# How to expose API to developers securely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hi I want to expose API of my web application to the developers so that they can build application on top of my API.
I want to develop it same as twitter does that means I want to build Consumer key,Consumer secret,Request token URL,Authorize URL,Access token URL,Callback URL,Access token,Access token secret.

I know some basics of Oauth that is first we have to generate request token. the request token then gets autherized on successful login by user. Then we can exchange autherized request token with access token.

I want to implement all this in my rails application. But not getting how to start with. I don't have any previous exprience on building and exposing API so any guidelines will be greatly helpful.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:
http://stakeventures.com/articles/2007/11/26/how-to-turn-your-rails-site-into-an-oauth-provider